# Неверный возврат функции

Tags: javascript

Почему не возвращается результат выполнения функции?
При выводе в консоль `typeof(feet)` пишет `function`

```js
const m = obj.distance.value;
let ft = obj.convert_to;
if (ft == "ft") ft = 3.280;

const feet = (m, ft) => ((m * ft).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: а где здесь выполнение функции?

Comment: typeof(feet) вам и будет возвращать function т.к это функция. Попробуйте typeof(feet())

Comment: Ничего не понял, но заработало)) Спасибо!!!

Comment: @ДмитрийОлейник, а зачем вообще было писать `(m, ft) =>`?

Comment: я хотел,чтобы с этими параметрами сразу выводился результат

Comment: @ДмитрийОлейник Скажу чуть иначе: вы пытались узнать тип функции, а я вам предложил узнать тип результата функции

Comment: Я хотел как раз то, что вы мне предложили, вот только сформулировал как-то нет видимо

Comment: @ДмитрийОлейник Вот это https://learn.javascript.ru/object-methods#vnutrennyaya-realizatsiya-ssylochnyy-tip почитайте, станет понятнее

Comment: @ДмитрийОлейник, тебе эта часть не нужна. Оставь просто `const feet =((m * ft).toFixed(2));`

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

в этой строке

```
const feet = (m, ft) => ((m * ft).toFixed(2));
```

просто объявляется функция с именем `feet`. Чтобы она что-то вернула, нужно её вызывать вот так:

```
feet(1, 22); // числа от балды
```

и только тогда можно применить *что-то* на **результате выполненной функции**, в т.ч. и `typeof`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!